# Angular redirect within await async method odd behaviour

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I have FCM messaging notification being received by the app fine but when trying to trigger a router navigation (if a call is received I want to display a page which looks like the standard Android incoming call page). I have a simple listener for pushNotificationReceived

```ts
 await PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived', notification => {
      this.logger.info(`[PUSH NOTIFICATION] - Push notification received: [Title: ${notification.title}, Body : ${notification.body}]`);

      if (notification.data && notification.data.IncomingCall) {
        this.logger.info(`INCOMING CALL FROM ${notification.data.CallerName}`);
        this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
        this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
        this.router.navigate(['/incomingcall']);
      } else {
        this.showNotificationDialog(notification.title || '', notification.body || '');
      }
    });
```

But whilst this code executes the screen does not change and seems to be slightly "corrupted" as controls/clicks are unresponsive.

I added router debugging and it shows routing is happening but doesn't seem to complete as I have logging on the component ngInit which should log out.

```
Line 1 - Msg: %c2022-03-23T13:43:07.094Z INFO [main.1554ef6f3488783a.js:1:377716] color:gray [PUSH NOTIFICATION] - Push notification received: [Title: Incoming call, Body : undefined]
 Line 1 - Msg: %c2022-03-23T13:43:07.095Z INFO [main.1554ef6f3488783a.js:1:377850] color:gray INCOMING CALL FROM Frank
 Line 1 - Msg: Router Event: pg
 Line 1 - Msg: NavigationStart(id: 2, url: '/incomingcall')
 Line 1 - Msg: Router Event: FB
 Line 1 - Msg: RoutesRecognized(id: 2, url: '/incomingcall', urlAfterRedirects: '/incomingcall', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'incomingcall', path:'incomingcall') } )
 Line 1 - Msg: Router Event: NB
 Line 1 - Msg: GuardsCheckStart(id: 2, url: '/incomingcall', urlAfterRedirects: '/incomingcall', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'incomingcall', path:'incomingcall') } )
 Line 1 - Msg: Router Event: HB
 Line 1 - Msg: ChildActivationStart(path: '')
 Line 1 - Msg: Router Event: jB
 Line 1 - Msg: ActivationStart(path: 'incomingcall')
 Line 1 - Msg: Router Event: LB
 Line 1 - Msg: GuardsCheckEnd(id: 2, url: '/incomingcall', urlAfterRedirects: '/incomingcall', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'incomingcall', path:'incomingcall') } , shouldActivate: true)
 Line 1 - Msg: Router Event: VB
 Line 1 - Msg: ResolveStart(id: 2, url: '/incomingcall', urlAfterRedirects: '/incomingcall', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'incomingcall', path:'incomingcall') } )
 Line 1 - Msg: Router Event: BB
 Line 1 - Msg: ResolveEnd(id: 2, url: '/incomingcall', urlAfterRedirects: '/incomingcall', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'incomingcall', path:'incomingcall') } )
 Line 1 - Msg: Router Event: UB
 Line 1 - Msg: ActivationEnd(path: 'incomingcall')
 Line 1 - Msg: Router Event: $B
 Line 1 - Msg: ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
 Line 1 - Msg: Router Event: Nl
 Line 1 - Msg: NavigationEnd(id: 2, url: '/incomingcall', urlAfterRedirects: '/incomingcall')
 Line 1 - Msg: Router Event: ME
 Line 1 - Msg: Scroll(anchor: 'null', position: 'null')
```

My app.component.html is simply a  with the Home.Component being used as the layout and thus having its own router-outlet. The router module is

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'incomingcall',
    component: IncomingCallComponent
  }, 
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/contacts',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      { path: 'contacts', component: ContactsComponent },
....
```

Having put text tags around the router-outlet in each component I notice that the new page is *almost* working as it **is** being displayed within the app.component router outlet but the page within the home.component router-outlet is continuing to be shown! Like this

```
<Appcomponent-router-outlet>
    <HomeComponent-router-outlet>
        <Contacts Page>
    </HomeComponent-router-outlet>
        <IncomingCall Page>
</Appcomponent-router-outlet>
```

I tried to recreate this in stackblitz but wasnt able to reproduce the issue - I suspect due to the PushNotification.addListener not being faithfully reproduced but in case it helps [Its here](https://angular-ivy-3pnexc.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix was to run the router navigate within the ngZone as per below

```
  this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/incomingcall'));
```

I imagine it is forcing more high level change detection of a larger area.

Hopefully this will prove useful to someone else who may find themselves in the same situation.